# middlePoint in CGContextAddArc?

Tags: iphone, ipad, math, cgcontext

i am drawing Arc  through CGCOntext.I want to draw a string in the center Point of Arc.how can i fond the center point in the Arc which has been drawn through CGContext.

```
              CGContextSetAlpha(ctx, 0.5);
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, color.red, color.green, color.blue, color.alpha );
CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, cX, cY);
CGContextAddArc(ctx, cX, cY, radious+10, (startDeg-90)*M_PI/180.0, (endDeg-90)*M_PI/180.0, 0);
CGContextClosePath(ctx);
CGContextFillPath(ctx);
```

Answer (score 1):

The 2nd and 3rd arguments to CGContextAddArc are the x and y coordinates for the center of the arc. Therefore, in this code, the center is at the point (cX,cY).

**Edit**

This code will give the coordinates for the point directly between the starting and ending points of the arc as x and y.

```
CGFloat x = cX + (radious+10) * (cos((startDeg-90)*M_PI/180.0) + cos((endDeg-90)*M_PI/180.0)) / 2;
CGFloat y = cY + (radious+10) * (sin((startDeg-90)*M_PI/180.0) + sin((endDeg-90)*M_PI/180.0)) / 2;
```

Comment: hi.. i did not ask the circle center in this code.... middle point in the arc part between two radious...

Comment: Oh, I see what you want. You should edit the post to ask for the middle point, not the center point, to avoid future confusion.